# How to add one picture to the left side of HTML page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm trying to add one picture to the left side of this page I know basic of HTML. Any suggestion?
Following is not woking? Do I need two container or something wrong?

```
<?
session_start();
$_SESSION['usertmp'];
$_SESSION['emailtmp'];
if(strlen($_SESSION['usertmp'])<1 ||is_null($_SESSION['usertmp']))
{
    $_SESSION['usertmp'] = "";
}
if(strlen($_SESSION['emailtmp'])<1 ||is_null($_SESSION['emailtmp']))
{
    $_SESSION['emailtmp'] = "";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Show Information</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {height:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}

#page-background {position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#content {position:relative; z-index:1; padding:10px;}

#
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-background"><img src="images/main.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" alt="Smile"></div>
<left>
<div class="container" style="width:800px" id="content">
<div class="header"><img src="images/logoo.png" width="177" height="61" longdesc="main.php" />
</left>
<center>
<div class="container" style="width:800px" id="content">
  <div class="header"><img src="images/logoo.png" width="177" height="61" longdesc="main.php" />                                <!-- end .header --></div>
<center>
  <div class="content" style="background-image:url(); height:427px; color: #FFF;vertical-align:middle">
    <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table> 

<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
<tr>
<form name="form2" method="post" action="signup.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><strong> Sign Up Here</strong></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username</td>
<td width="6">:</td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" value = "<? echo $_SESSION['usertmp'] ?>"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Enter Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Confirm Password</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="mypassword2" type="password" id="mypassword2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email id</td>
<td>:</td>
<td><input name="myemail" type="text" id="myemail" value = "<? echo $_SESSION['emailtmp'] ?>"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>

  </div>
    </center>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: showing your .css would help a lot

Comment: Well, for starters, your HTML is invalid. You have a `<td>` as a child of a `<form>` and the `<center>` tag was deprecated ages ago.

Comment: .header > img{float:left}

Comment: @AlexShilman that would cause two images to float to the left.
I assume the OP only wants the image within the <left> tag to be floated to the left.
If I'm correct, in your css you will want to do: left .header{float:left;}.

Comment: please learn to close the tags in the order in which you opened them

Comment: can you mention which img to be in left side

Comment: @caramba Here is the full file. I don't have any css file? Anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways you could achieve what you are looking to do. You should try to simplify your markup if you can. If you want to keep your login credential table in the middle. Here is a way to do it using 3 main divs as 32.98% width columns. Float them left and use the first column for the pic that you want on the left. Here it is in jsbin. Of course the images aren't working bc it doesn't have access to the proper path http://jsbin.com/muxac/1/edit

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
<style>
    .col-1, .col-2, .col-3 {
        width: 32.98%;
        float:left;
    }

</style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<header class="header">

</header>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <div class="header"><img src="images/logoo.png" width="177" height="61" longdesc="main.php" /></div>
    </div> <!-- End of COLUMN 1 --> 

    <div class="col-2"> <!-- Start of COLUMN 2 -->

        <div class="header"><img src="images/logoo.png" width="177" height="61" longdesc="main.php" />
            <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
                <tr>
                    <form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"><strong>Member Login </strong></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="78">Username</td>
                                    <td width="6">:</td>
                                    <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
                <tr>
                    <form name="form2" method="post" action="signup.php">
                        <td>
                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="3"><p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        <p><strong> Sign Up Here</strong></p></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="78">Username</td>
                                    <td width="6">:</td>
                                    <td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername" value = "<? echo $_SESSION['usertmp'] ?>"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Enter Password</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Confirm Password</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="mypassword2" type="password" id="mypassword2"></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Email id</td>
                                    <td>:</td>
                                    <td><input name="myemail" type="text" id="myemail" value = "<? echo $_SESSION['emailtmp'] ?>"></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up"></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>  <!-- End of COLUMN 2 --> 
    <div class="col-3"> <!-- COLUMN 3 --> 
        <!-- You can leave this empty if you want -->
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="footer">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This looks perfect. loogoo is working. Only I need to position the background image.

Comment: background image for the entire page or a certain part of the page? If it is the entire page - did you try to put it on the body element? EG. `body {background: url(../path/to/background-image);}`

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is just the header image to be at the top left, put inside the `<style>` this: `.header img {display: inline-block; float: left;}`

Answer (score 0):

To position the picture You can use CSS. Here is the code(Insert it in the style attribute of the html tag):

```
position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px/*Here inserte the necesary pixels to position the picture*/
```